# Error while Selecting 4,000 rows from MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, server, web-hosting

Error occurred when i tried this loop more than 3 times.
I am trying to load this data into a HTML Table view in my webpage

```
$offset=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $offset = ($i * 1000);
    if ($i == 0) {
        $offset = "";
    }
    unset($stmt); unset($products);
    $query=("SELECT * FROM tbldata A order by A.no asc limit ".$offset.",1000");
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

[Error occurred when i tried this loop more than 3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvMT.png)

Comment: You should check your PHP error log. That'll probably answer your question .

Comment: Did you look at the server error log?

Comment: echo and show us the error generating the query

Comment: Check your PHP/Webserver error logs. It could be that you are running out of memory or something entirely different.

Comment: I bet that you hit top limitation of memory per php process.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough

$offset = $i * 1000;

Remove :

```
$offset = ",".($i * 1000);
    if ($i == 0) {
        $offset = "";
    }
```

Replace :

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM tbldata A order by A.no asc limit ".$offset.",1000");
```

with :

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbldata A order by A.no asc limit ".$offset.",1000";
```

Comment: remove the brackets